# Not loading javascript on Local IIS but it is working on IIS Express

Tags: javascript, iis

I need java script to load correctly on Local IIS.
I am using IIS 8.5

I am realy laic for IIS, but what I have done so far:

- I have 'Static content' turned on
- I gave permission to 'everyone' to my Java script folder

There are some duplicate questions [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512053/css-images-js-not-loading-in-iis) , and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400717/iis-8-5-is-not-serving-js-css-and-image-files-static-content), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037933/windows-8-iis-does-not-load-stylesheets-and-images-in-asp-net-app).
But nothing is helpful in my case.

Do you know how to find out what is issue in my case ?

Comment: Too few diagnostic info here. Are you able to navigate on a plain .html page? What is the http status of the call to your javascript file? ...

Comment: Yes, it is working fine without javascript. My home page is 'https ://ComputerName/ Client.Web/Home/Index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solution.

I find out that it works in all browsers except IE.

Solution is to add meta tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

See [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/2451446)